# Storing to a variable vs passing directly (does that implicitly create a temp variable?)

Tags: objective-c

**Model 1**

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)[response valueForKey:@"name"];
[someObject doSomethingWith:name];
```

**Model 2**

```
[someObject doSomethingWith:((NSString *)[response valueForKey:@"name"])];
```

If i chose model 2 will that save a variable created on the stack Or still an implicit temp variable created behind he scene?

Ignoring loss of readability, is there any benefit in avoiding creating variable that will be used in only place. Instead passing it directly as in model 2?

Comment: Side note - the `NSString` casts aren't needed since `valueForKey:` has a return type of `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generated by the compiler will be the same, however, there's no variable in the second case. A variable is a high-level programming concept, the resulting assembly code knows about registers and memory only. And in both cases, the return value of the innermost method call needs to be stored somewhere, so either a register or place on the stack will be used for that.

Also, `id` (what `- [NSDictionary valueForKey:]` returns) is generic and implicitly compatible with any object pointer type - please, don't cast its return value to `NSString *`.